# How do I create foreign keys in Azure DB?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

How do I create foreign keys in Azure DB ?
I can't find it in the silver-light Azure DB manager and when I connect with SSMS, when I don't get the same GUI options to add foreign keys.
Do I really have to use manually written scripts to accomplish this? (Yes I'm lazy)

**EDIT**: I guess I could create my schema in SQL SERVER - EXPORT AND IMPORT.... I will try that and report.
(Creating it on SQL server and exporting and running on Azure worked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no GUI available to do this.

However, if you have Red Gate SQL Compare, you can use it to synchronize changes in schema from a local SQL server to SQL Azure with a few clicks.

HTH

Comment: Thanks -- I will do this. Seems kinda like a big oversight.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to connect to Azure and edit the database directly. Or you could use a free service like http://www.queryanywhere.com/.

Full disclosure: I work for Red Gate